# json get the right code

Tags: php, json

Currently trying to get this code to print everything in the array but there is a small 
problem.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zettslive/follows?limit=10&offset=0');  

$vid_arr = json_decode($json,true);
$vid_count  = count($vid_arr);

foreach ($vid_arr as $vid)
{ 
echo '<img src="'.$vid[1]['user']['logo'].'">';
}
```

I have to use the `[1]` to even get it to work. and I want to be able to echo them all. and not do them one at a time.

Comment: That's nice. Questions usually end with a `?` character, and generally "how do I get the right data from this data structure"-type questions would include the target data structure...

Comment: What's the issue?  Does your code work?  What does it echo?  What should it echo?

Comment: Maybe you should actually look at the data you're getting back. Perhaps if you would see that the array isn't at the root, but rather under the key, `follows`, you would know that you should do `foreach ($vir_arr['follows']...` which would have taken you roughly 10 seconds to debug with the handy `var_dump` function

Comment: Thanks for the headsup on the follow, still new to php and I missed the `follows` part. Issue solved. Also sorry about not making the question more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/zettslive/follows?limit=10&offset=0');  

$vid_arr = json_decode($json,true);
$vid_count  = count($vid_arr);

foreach ($vid_arr['follows'] as $follow)
{ 
echo '<img src="'.$follow['user']['logo'].'">';
}
```